# Microsoft BotBuilder-Calling : Taking input from user

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, skype

I am working on Microsoft bot-builder calling with skype , And created an application on Node.JS Application. All basic functionality is working fine however there is a scenario to ask user input and store what user have answered with no prior choices available.Please check the code below :

```
function (session) {
        session.send("Welcome to the dinner reservation.Please tell ur name ?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        console.log("result---->"+JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

I am trying to capture the user result for which i have asked the question in session.send.However I am getting `{"resumed":0}`in logs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

EDITED: I didn't notice it, but you are simply sending a message and what you should do is PROMPT the user for his/her name. Try the following:

```
function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text("Welcome to the dinner reservation.Please tell ur name ?");
    },
function (session, results) {
        console.log("result---->" + results.response);
}
```

Comment: I edited my solution, have you tried using prompts? With your current solution, you are not asking the user for his/her name, you are just sending a message

Comment: Thanks jbeltran, Could you please share the correct way to ask a question from user and handle the user response.

Comment: I already shared the correct way to ask a question. First you have to use a Prompt to ask for the name and then you get the name with results.response. It's been reflected in the answer already ;)

Comment: Okay @jbeltran, I have already tried using `builder.prompts.text`  and  `calling.prompts.text`. both gives error that is:- oops , something went wrong.

Comment: "Oops something went wrong" is the string that is shown in the emulator. What is the error in the console? I suggest you try one on the simplest samples (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt) given by Microsoft, it does exactly the same you want to

Comment: Thanks @jbeltran ,But there is no error in console and i was following this [https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Calling/blob/master/Node/examples/demo-skype-calling/app.js ] and this blog[https://sweetcode.io/azure-bot-builder-sdk-nodejs/   ] .  If you don't mind and if you have time, we can connect on skype or other bridge for a short period of time.